# move_uploaded_file() wont move the file at all

Tags: phpstorm

Can't get any image into my uploads folder. PHPStorm locked the folder, how Can I unlock that?

```
<label for="product-title">Product Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="file">


    $image = escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $image_temp  = escape_string($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    move_uploaded_file($image_temp, UPLOAD_DIR . DS . $image);
```

Unchecked Read Only in Windows 10 uploads folder settings, still no luck.

Comment: What are 'UPLOAD_DIR' and 'DS' values?

Comment: define("UPLOAD_DIR", __DIR__ . DS . "uploads");